# When a java application executes the Rserve binary, the Rconnection fails

Tags: java, r, runtime, rserve

when I call the Rserve application within my java code with a runtime class the following evaluation commands fail.

But if I start the Rserve application from a terminal there is no error in the evaluation.

Comment: You need to provide more information (like error messages, sample code with expected behavior) for people to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

See `StartRserve.java` in the examples on how to run Rserve from Java.

Most common mistakes:

- If you start any process form Java, you must provide I/O readers otherwise it will kill the process on any output.
- When starting `R` outside of tty, there are mandatory flags you must provide. See the `R` error on details what it expects (typically people use at least `--no-save`).